# Change p tag to input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using AngularJS to build a small SPA. Coming from a jQuery background I have trouble with things like DOM manipulation (or lack thereof) in AngularJS. I have an ng-repeat that creates tr's - what I'd like to happen, is when the end-user clicks on one of the p tags within the td, it converts into an editable input field.

From:
[image: ng-repeat initial]

On p tag click:
[image: ng-repeat with edit]

Here's the code that I currently have:
index.html
`<tr ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <td>
        <span ng-click='edit()'>{{test.name}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>`

controllers.js
`$scope.edit = function() {
    something in here that will help me convert to input type='text'
}`

I'm thinking I need to use a directive, so if someone can point me in the right direction or let me know what I can do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Maybe an example of inline editing using angular helps. See http://jsfiddle.net/bonamico/cahz7/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ki3diA6WIf9ZU99FH42a?p=preview

Comment: Looks like the directive was the right way to go. I'm assuming from your fiddle that the divs within the td's I can create with ng-repeat, would that be safe to assume?

Comment: dfsq, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! If either of you you make it an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple, you can use `ng-hide` and `ng-show` along with an `isEditing` flag:

```
<tr ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!isEditing" ng-click='isEditing = !isEditing'>{{test.name}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-show="isEditing" ng-model="test.name" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

You'll need to add a button to save the edits and flip the `isEditing` flag back over - but other than that this should work.

Comment: It will not work with common `isEditing` flag, because it will toggle edit for all tests.

Comment: @dfsq -- There is no common `isEditing` flag - it's within the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: So this has the input existing in the html, but hides the input with the matching ng-model as the p tag until the isEditing flag is set to false?

Comment: @AndresL -- Each `ng-repeat` creates it's own scope - the `isEditing` flag is on each repeated scope. The `input` is hidden on each repeat until the edit button is clicked, then it is shown because `isEditing` is now `true` just for that repeat.

Comment: works perfectly, and is much simpler than using a directive. Thanks tymeJV

Answer (score 0):

The angular way would be to use ng-class, which can decide the class for a dom object on the basis of a boolean object in your $scope.

Briefly, you create the input field beforehand, but it starts off with a class that hides it (display:none).
When you click on the p tag you set a boolean in your $scope called, say, 'showField1' to true, and ng-class changes the class for the input field to a class with display:block.

You do the same with your p tag, which starts off with display:block but when you click on it, ng-class can switch the class to another one with display:hide

Simple. You don't need a directive.